# App only works when logged on to the desktop

Tags: high-sierra

I have an application that needs to be always working on a MacMini, I use crontab to start it but in High Sierra and Mojave, the app only works normally after logging on to the desktop.  I need it to be working even without being logged in. It worked normally in Sierra !
I start the app in crontab with the command:

```
 @reboot su - user -c "sleep 20 ; application"
```

and a script restart it if there's a problem!
Any idea how I can fix this? TIA

Comment: I have no experience using cron on a Mac... Do you know about Services and Daemons using launchd?

Comment: little knowledge , I come from linux , so I use what freebsd core of the Mac has to offer

Comment: I feel you, on a *nix or linux distro cron or systemd (and variations thereof) would be my go-to tool, but on a Mac, I really think you want to use launchd. I recommend looking at the documentation on it, [LaunchControl](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) is a GUI app that I think gives you a good understanding of how launchd works in a broad sense.

Comment: I agree, I'm seeing the launchd documentation right now, thank you.

Comment: Just to check, the application doesn't need the window server running in order to function right?

Comment: The application is an image server and needs to log in to run normal, but I'm not sure if it needs the Windowsserver because I forcequit the windowsserver and it still ran normal.  The problem occurs when I start the app without being logged in, if I do the loggin then I start the app and exit , it works normal.